# When fetching a model friends a ACS search Request is done but this is deprecated

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

When fetching a model friends a search is done but this is deprecated. The logging shows to use $text query instead.

Logging:

```
    [INFO] :   ACS Request: { url: "friends/search.json", verb: "GET", data: {} })
[INFO] :   GET: https://api.cloud.appcelerator.com/v1/friends/search.json?key=PVLeRMfhektJkgscd48vlk0M6WULJZNa&_session_id=k4cmGr1FIe5-Z79fJj_2JVeOEcg&suppress_response_codes=true&ti_analytics=%7B%22id%22%3A%225FBE6E68-C348-49B3-8630-D38994A8C512%22%2C%22mid%22%3A%22C08AF0DE-C973-4C06-8938-644BD78D1F6A%22%2C%22aguid%22%3A%22fa071e63-8155-40c2-9888-9d1a8d19620a%22%2C%22event%22%3A%22cloud.friends.search%22%2C%22deploytype%22%3A%22development%22%2C%22sid%22%3A%222390147D-4EBE-4EFC-A8F7-1F84E3389485%22%7D
[INFO] :   header: {}
[INFO] :   data: {}
[INFO] :   Fetched collection: [object Object]
[ERROR] :  410: search.json has been deprecated. Please use $text query
[ERROR] :  Cloud.Friends.query search.json has been deprecated. Please use $text query
```

Controller friends.js:

```
var Cloud = require('ti.cloud');
$.usrWindowButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
var collection = Alloy.createCollection("friends");
collection.fetch(); // GET: read
});
```

Model friends.js:

```
exports.definition = {
    config : {
        "adapter" : {
            "type" : "acs",
            "collection_name" : "friends"
        }   },
    extendModel : function(Model) {
        _.extend(Model.prototype, {
        });
        return Model;
    },
    extendCollection : function(Collection) {
        _.extend(Collection.prototype, {
        });
        return Collection;
    }
,};
```

How can I force it to make the `friends/query.json` ACS request instead of making `friends/search.json`?

Please can someone help me out, it's much appreciated.

### Update

Updated tiSDK, alloy, ti.cloud module still have the same problem.

```
Operating System
  Name                        = Mac OS X
  Version                     = 10.11
  Architecture                = 64bit
  # CPUs                      = 4
  Memory                      = 4294967296
Node.js
  Node.js Version             = 4.0.0
  npm Version                 = 2.14.2
Titanium CLI
  CLI Version                 = 5.0.9
Titanium SDK
  SDK Version                 = 5.5.1.GA
  SDK Path                    = /Users/michielvanschilt/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA
  Target Platform             = iphone
Command
  /usr/local/bin/node /Users/michielvanschilt/.appcelerator/install/5.5.1/package/node_modules/titanium/lib/titanium.js build run --platform ios --log-level trace --sdk 5.5.1.GA --project-dir /Users/michielvanschilt/RTF2016/RTF --target simulator --ios-version 9.3 --device-family iphone --deploy-type development --sim-type iphone --sim-version 9.3 --device-id 52E0E31B-0701-48F4-B5DE-CDA86FBE951F --skip-js-minify --no-colors --no-progress-bars --no-prompt --prompt-type socket-bundle --prompt-port 63974 --config-file /var/folders/bn/9d8d9vyj2bb7l74fhdr6hs3h0000gn/T/build-1480602293433.json --no-banner --project-dir /Users/michielvanschilt/RTF2016/RTF
[INFO] :   Found Titanium module id=ti.cloud version=3.2.9 platform=commonjs deploy-type=development path=/Users/michielvanschilt/Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules/commonjs/ti.cloud/3.2.9
[INFO] :   Found better matching module id=ti.cloud version=latest platform=commonjs deploy-type=development path=/Users/michielvanschilt/Library/Application Support/Titanium/modules/commonjs/ti.cloud/3.2.11
```

Comment: have you updated the module?

Comment: Hi @RenePot , sorry I don't know what you mean by updating the model, so I probably didn't.

Comment: module! acs is a module you need to include in tiapp. If you run an old TiSDK your model probably is outdated too. So update!

Comment: @RenePot, I tried updating the ti.cloud module and now uses the latest version. I still have the same issue. I added some logging to the post, could you take a look again?